# If $f, g$ are continuous and $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx \ge \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx$. Is the inverse true?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

The proof for the first statement is trivial using the definition of Riemann sums, since

\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i^*) \Delta x \ge \lim_{x \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(x_i^*)\Delta x = \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx
\end{equation}

for any sample point $x_i^*$.

But is the inverse true? Namely, if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx \ge \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx$, then $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. I couldn't think of any counterexamples where this is true, and trying to adapt the above 'proof' did not work well since we cannot conclude that $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for every $x \in [a,b]$ simply from the sums alone.

Is there a mistake in my thinking? Otherwise, a relevant counter-example (if it is wrong) or a hint for a proof would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The $x$ in $\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge\int_a^bg(x)dx$ is a dummy variable. It doesn't make all that much sense that the statement holds "for all $x\in[a,b]$. Try to think about this graphically. Can you draw two graphs such that the area under one is greater than the area under the other without the former graph lying entirely above the other?

Comment: Oops, sorry, the for all statement would be more relevant for the conclusion (I'll be editing it). Intuitively I understand your comment on the visualization using graphs, but then again this is only geometric intuition, and I was looking for some help with a rigorous proof, if any.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can try to visualize a counter-example. If you can do that graphically, it won't be hard to explicitly write it down either.

Comment: If i understand what you're trying to ask correctly, you are looking for continuous $f$ and $g$ such that $\int f \ge \int g$ but $f(x)\not \ge g(x)$ for all $x$ in the interval. Well, consider $\sin$ and $\cos$ and a suitable interval. You should find it easy that neither function is greater than the other but the integral inequality holds

Comment: Take $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = 1/2$ and $[a,b]=[0,2]$.

Comment: Both your examples helped me greatly. Thank you! I apologize once again if my question was vague.

Comment: For any pair of real-valued functions $f$ and $g$, either $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx \ge \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx$ or else $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx \ge \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx$. If your "inverse" statement were true, then for any pair of real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ you would have either $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ or else $g(x)\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Do you believe that? Can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is to ask the equivalent question for series, that is if $\sum_k f_k \ge \sum_k g_k$ is $f_k \ge g_k$ (not true, for same reasons as above).